# telnetlib read_until buffer size

Tags: python, buffer, telnetlib

Background:
I am pulling the connection table of a firewall in order to build a top talkers/listeners list.

In some cases, the connection table is 200,000+ entries. I am using telnetlib to remote to the firewall and grab the connection table. I use read_until to capture the data. However, when the table is larger than 40,000 entries it hangs. When I kill it, I see the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test2.py", line 152, in ?
main()
File "test2.py", line 120, in main
tmp_text = telnet.read_until(pager_text)
File "/usr/lib/python2.3/telnetlib.py", line 317, in read_until
self.process_rawq()
File "/usr/lib/python2.3/telnetlib.py", line 488, in process_rawq
self.cookedq = self.cookedq + buf[0]
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Am I hitting some sort of buffer? What would be a better way to obtain this data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The last time I used telnetlib was a long while back, but... to the best of my knowledge using `read_until` is best suited for sessions with more interactivity and less occurrences of huge data dumps. The idea being that you are waiting for a specific pattern response to then communicate again.

Have you tried one of the other read options such as `read_some` and building up your response on your local side? It could definitely be a matter of buffer like you said.

You could also try `read_until` and give it a timeout value, and see if you can get at least part of the data, and then read again.

Also, I noticed you are using python2.3 . If you aren't bound to that version, I noticed in the source of telnetlib that more recent changes improved the timeout handling specifically.

Comment: Thanks - I'll play with read_some and see if it helps. Python 2.3.4 is the standard on our servers and isn't something I can upgrade unfortunately.